# Как конвертировать символ в цифру?

Tags: c++

Есть переменная типа `string`, в неё записывается строка, введённая пользователем с клавиатуры. Нужно посчитать сумму всех цифр в этой строке.

Проблема в том, что не удаётся перевести символьную цифру в цифровую цифру. Пробовал юзать функцию `atoi`, но она выдаёт неправильный результат.

Мой код:

```
string s;
//code code...
cin>>s;
//code code...
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    cout<<s[i]<<" ";
    if((int)s[i]>47 && (int)s[i]<58)
    {
        count++;
        sum+=atoi(&s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код с atoi() приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Для перевода десятичной цифры из символьного представления в двоичное просто вычтите из ее символьного представления символ '0'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А еще навскидку, для обучения:

```
int summ = 0;
for (int i=0; i < myString.length(); ++i) {
    char c = myString[i];
    summ += c - '0';
}
```

Правда для уверенного использования понадобится проверочку добавить. Хотя она у вас и так уже сделана:

```
string s;
//code code...
cin>>s;
//code code...
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    cout<<s[i]<<" ";
    if((int)s[i]>47 && (int)s[i]<58)
    {
        sum += s[i] - '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему без - '0' не работает? Чем мешает 0?

Comment: Так как за переменной типа char в общем случае сокрыт код символа (в вашем случае это коды от 48 - '0' и 57 - '9', чтобы простейшим способом перевести из char в реальное число, нужно от исходного кода отнять код нуля, что мы собственно и сделали.

Comment: Аа, вот оно что, хитро )

Comment: Подозреваю, что за функцией `atoi` сей алгоритм и спрятан.

Comment: Все правильно. Для проверки, является ли символ цифрой, можно (и хорошо) воспользоваться функцией isdigit() из cctypes.

Comment: isdigit() - куда уж тривиальней)) Можно, конечно, и так, как написано. Это не будет ошибкой, естественно, и все будет работать. Но использование стандартной функции сделает код более... читабельным, что ли. Да и как-то это культурно - использовать стандартные функции. Дело функции. Я предложил лишь как вариант.

Comment: @mikillskegg, я ни в коем случае не осуждаю, вы не подумайте. Просто дополнительную библиотеку ради одной функции, не перебор ли?

Comment: Вообще-то эта функция содержится в libc, которая подключается к любой программе на C/С++. А заголовки далеко не всегда идут по принципу "один заголовок - одна библиотека"...

Comment: "Подозреваю, что за функцией atoi сей алгоритм и спрятан." 

 atoi() ищет начало числа (пропускает "пробелы"), учитывает знак и останавливается по первой же не цифре, а также перед сложением умножает уже накопленную сумму на 10. А в остальном похоже.

Comment: @mikillskegg, спасибо за разъяснения, я в `С` не особенно разбираюсь, с библиотеками мало знаком.

Comment: @skegg: стоит заметить, что [легко можно ошибиться при вызове `isdigit()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/50533/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%83#comment50556_50536). `'0'..'9'`  гарантированно подряд идут, но я не помню, что численные значения конкретные в стандарте гарантированны.

Answer (score 3):

Atoi преобразовывает строку в число. А символ - это не строка. Код будет например таким:

```
...
int summ = 0; //переменная в которой будет сумма всех цифр
int i = 0;
for (; i < myString.length(); ++i)
{
    char buff[2]; //массив который будет хранить один символ
    buff[0] = myString[i];
    buff[1] = '\0' //символ конца строки
    summ += atoi(buff);
}
...
```

Comment: но работает и без строчки buff[1] = '\0' , зачем она нужна?

Comment: atoi() берет строку, а строка должна завершаться **двоичным нулем**. 

У Вас "и без строчки buff[1] = '\\0'" работало только потому, что он (двоичный ноль) там  случайно оказался.

Comment: Можно, конечно, и так. Только как-то громоздко получилось.

Comment: Да, правильный (с учетом комментариев) ответ дал @Dex. Похоже, автор вопроса его не понял. Я объяснял насчет конца строки.

Answer (score 3):

В общем, подводя итог предложениям предыдущих авторов, предлагаю такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int strsum (const string & str ) {
    int sum = 0, len = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        if (isdigit(str[i])) sum += str[i] - '0';   
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    string st;
    cin >> st;
    cout << strsum (st) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [чтобы избежать undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279) в этом случае, если  `char` со знаком, лучше `std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))` использовать.  Также [`isdigit()` может от локали на Windows зависеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385335/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Еще так можно ([ideone](http://ideone.com/83Mf0F)):

```
string s = "12345";
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c){return c-'0';});
int sum = accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
cout << sum << endl;
```

но это только на тот случай, если все символы - цифры.

Answer (score 0):

здесь, вроде тот-же вопрос обсуждается...
[вот](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/s/379f6d2196f9106a818ad49cc36658cd/topic-183117/anchor-entry1323578/0.html)

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
//вот мой вариант(только для char)
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int conv(char c){
return c-'0';
}
//для конвертации string'a предлагаю использовать перегрузку для вводимого типа
//после чего возвращаемый результат посимвольно конвертируется и добваляется к 
//возвращаемому результату.
```

Comment: Кажись, там другое немного обсуждается.

Comment: Там нужно сосчитать сумму ЦИФР, которые находятся в строке, т.е. все остальные символы нужно игнорировать => делать проверку каждого символа, цифра ли это.