# Считывание данных из файла с произвольной строки

Tags: c

У меня есть следующий текстовый файл:

```
Input data:
 N         tn         t1         t2         tk         u1         u2
21        5.000     20.000     50.000     65.000    100.000     95.000

 i       Time        Uvx      Uvix
 1      5.000      0.000      0.000
 2      8.000     20.000     50.000
 3     11.000     40.000     50.000
 4     14.000     60.000     50.000
 5     17.000     80.000     50.000
 6     20.000    100.000     50.000
 7     23.000     99.500     50.000
 8     26.000     99.000     50.000
 9     29.000     98.500     50.000

Длительность переднего фронта:

  Uvx      Uvix
 9.000      0.000
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы считать с этого файла все числовые значения, минуя при этом строки с названиями переменных и прочим текстом, а также пустые строки. Так вот как пропустить эти самые строки и начать считывать данные с произвольной строки? Язык - Си.

Comment: А что мешает просто пропустить первые `n` строк?

Comment: @VladD, может, я сейчас задам глупый вопрос, но как пропустить эти n строк?

Comment: @Иван Кущёв, если размер каждой из них в байтах заранее неизвестен, то только последовательным чтением.

Comment: @avp, просто несколько раз подряд использовать функцию fscanf()?  Просто она вроде как начинает читать с первой строки. И, допустим, размер строк нам известен, тогда как решается эта задача?

Comment: На каком шаге возникли трудности? Ясно ли, как прочитать строку из ввода, предполагая, что длина самой большой строки фиксирована (e.g., `fgets()`)? Ясно ли, как пропустить не-числа в заданной строке (e.g., `strcspn()`)? Ясно ли, как можно прочитать несколько чисел, разделённых пробелами (e.g., `sscanf()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы избежать загрузки в память строк, которые всё равно будут проигнорированы и чтобы поддерживать произвольно большие входные строки, можно читать файл побайтно, используя `fgetc()`.

Чтобы пропустить строки до тех пор пока не встретится строка, которая начинается с цифры (строка с численными данными), игнорируя возможные пробелы, можно использовать автомат с двумя состояниями:

1. читаем до тех пор пока не прочитан символ новой строки (`\n`)
2. переходим в состояние ожидания цифры (`expect_digit=1`): все пробелы  и табы игнорируются, если прочитана цифра, то возвращаем её назад в поток и выходим из функции, в противном случае (не цифра) возвращаемся в начальное состояние 1.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

// read until a line that starts with a digit (ignoring leading hor.space)
int skip_until_line_startswith_digit(FILE* file)
{
  int expect_digit = 1; // expect a digit as the next character
  for (int c; (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF; ) {
    switch (c) {
    case '\n': // newline
      expect_digit = 1;
      break;
    case ' ': // horizontal whitespace
    case '\t':
      // ignore
      break;
    case '0': // digit
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
      if (expect_digit) {
        if (ungetc(c, file) == EOF)
          return -2; // error
        return 0; // found digit
      }
      // unexpected digit: ignore
      break;
    default: // everything else
      expect_digit = 0;
    }
  }
  return feof(file) ? -1 : -2; // not found or an error
}
```

`isdigit()` может зависеть от локали на Винде, поэтому она здесь не используется.

#### Пример использования

```
FILE* file = stdin;
if (skip_until_line_startswith_digit(file) < 0)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

// read 1st numeric block
size_t N;
double tn, t1, t2, tk, u1, u2;
errno = 0;
if (fscanf(file, "%zu %lf  %lf  %lf  %lf  %lf  %lf",
                  &N, &tn, &t1, &t2, &tk, &u1, &u2) != 7) {
  if (errno) perror("N tn t1 t2 tk u1 u2");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("%zu %f %f %f %f %f %f\n", N, tn, t1, t2, tk, u1, u2);
```

---

> А по поводу зависимости isdigit от
>   локали -- можно поподробнее (я думаю,
>   это всем будет интересно)? В каких
>   случаях это не будет работать для
>   распознавания чисел (и почему только в
>   винде)?

С стандарт говорит (например, см. [сноску в 7.11.1.1 в n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), что `isdigit()` не зависит от локали, но на Винде `isdigit()` может зависеть от локали, например, [`'\xb2'` в cp1252 кодировке в Danish локале](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440958/4279) распознается как десятичная цифра, что не правильно.

Кстати, Unicode стандарт солидарен с С стандартом: верхние индексы такие как [U+00B2](http://codepoints.net/U+00B2) явно исключены see [4.6 Numerical Value (Unicode 6.2)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch04.pdf).

Comment: @jfs, хорошая идея. И тогда уж лучше, если skip будет возвращать количество прочитанных `\n`. Это позволит сделать нормальную диагностику об ошибках (номер строки).

Ну, а perror после fscanf почти всегда будет выводить -- Success.

Может  стоит предусмотреть, что в принципе бывают отрицательные числа (кстати, scanf нормально читает и числа, которые начинаются с `+`).



-- 

А по поводу зависимости isdigit от локали -- можно поподробнее (я думаю, это всем будет интересно)? 

В каких случаях это не будет работать для распознавания *чисел* (и почему только в винде)?

Comment: @avp: добавил инфу о `isdigit()`.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. 

А то я уж начал фантазировать об иероглифах [〇, 一, 二, 三  ...  九](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)  
(шутка)

Comment: @avp: даже если добавить поддержку Юникодных чисел (придётся читать больше байта), эти иероглифы всё равно не являются [Юникодными десятичными цифрами](http://ideone.com/5lhDKc) :)

Comment: Конечно, не являются, также как и приведенные Вами из cp1252  
(раньше я о таких извратах и не подозревал).

Answer (score 3):

[[[[@Иван Кущёв](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2), fscanf не пойдет, т.к. она читает не по строкам. Можно, например, так:

```
 int c, nl = 0, skip_lines = сколько строк пропустить;

 while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
   if ((c == '\n') && (++nl == skip_lines))
     break;
 if (feof(f))
   fatal("Bad data");
```

Если размер строк, точнее смещение интересующей строки в файле известно (или его можно вычислить), то см. `man 3 fseek`.

**Обновление**

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), после `getline` free не нужна (а если вызывать free, тогда указатель опять надо обнулить).

Можно так (одной строкой):

```
 while (n-- && getline(&s, &len, file) > 0);
 if (n != -1)
   fatal(...);
 printf("last skipped line: %s", s);
```

только сожрет немного больше ресурсов (а вообще-то, я отвечая, просто и забыл про getline).

--

[[[[@Иван Кущёв](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/13967/%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2), м.б. на практике для Вашей задачи лучше просто пропустить строки до начала данных?

```
 while (getline(&s, &len, file) > 0 && *s != 'i');
```

а дальше читать построчно и использовать `sscanf(s, "%d %d %d %d", ...)` для выборки данных.

**Обновление**

Ага, пусть так. Идея-то остается. Все равно ведь 3 разных блока данных.

Просто 3 раза `while (getline(...) && ...);` потом чтение (один раз в цикле).

---

А если у автора в libc нет getline, то пусть напишет свою версию (заодно потренируется, тем более что во втором блоке данных ему может понадобиться динамический массив структур).

Comment: А почему не просто

    char* s = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    while (n--)
    {
        getline(&s, &len, file);
        free(s);
    }

(надеюсь, `getline` есть в стандарте.)

Comment: @avp: Точно! Я неправильно понял [документацию](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), сейчас перечитал и дошёл.

Comment: `getline()` в С нет. `getline()` есть в POSIX.

@avp: строки с `21` и ` 9.000` тоже нужно читать, т.е. нельзя `*s != 'i'` условие использовать.