# Посчитать сумму числ в строке с ограничением на разряды

Tags: c, массивы

Стоит задача  Написать программу, которая находит сумму чисел во введённой строке
Пояснение

Программа рассматривает непрерывные последовательности цифр в строке как числа и обрабатывает их как единое целое. В программе предусмотреть ограни- чение на максимальное число разрядов, то есть если пользователь вводит очень длинную последовательность цифр, её нужно разбить на несколько групп.

Пример:

"ab12cd45e" -> 57

Состав

Программа должна состоять из функций:

```
- int getSum(char buf[]) - нахождение суммы
- main().
```

Вопрос стоит как реализовать ограничение на максимальное число разрядов, тоесть если пользователь вводит последвательность из 4 символов то разбиваем их на две группы и считаем за два числа, должно быть примерно так dfg1234er45->12+34+45.
Вот код:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "task3.h"
#define N 512
int main()
{
    char buf[N] = { 0 };
    int sum = getSum(fgets(buf, N, stdin));
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}
#include <ctype.h>//for isdigit()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>//for atoi
int getSum(char *buf)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (*buf) {
        while (*buf && !isdigit(*buf))
            ++buf;
        sum += atoi(buf);
        while (*buf && isdigit(*buf))
            ++buf;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @PinkTux автору следует явно подчеркнуть отличие от предыдущего вопроса, но вопросы не дубликаты.

Comment: @jfs, вчитался и отозвал голос за дубликат. Хотя, конечно, не сразу понятна разница.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вводя ограничение на количество цифр в [ответ на предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754880/23044):

```
int sum_numbers(const char *s) {
  int sum = 0, n = 0, i = 0;
  for ( ; s && *s; ++s) {
    if ('0' <= *s && *s <= '9') {
      n = n * 10 + (*s - '0');
      if (++i == 4) {  // dddd
        sum += n / 100 + n % 100; // dd + dd
        n = 0;
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    else if (n) { // complete number
      sum += n;
      n = 0;
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  return sum + n;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Cua1O4).

Comment: Использование atoi()/strtol() может и оверхэд (использую их просто для наглядности), но какой смысл не использовать ctype.h? Сомневаюсь, что компилятор соптимизирует два сравнения до уровня проверки битовой маски :)

Comment: @PinkTux код в ответе—это минимально изменённая версия [кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754880/23044), который был написан не для производительности, а для простоты и корректности.  К примеру, isdigit() может неверный результат выдать на Windows и делает менее очевидным, что `c-'0'` делает.

Comment: *isdigit() может неверный результат выдать на Windows* -- это как?

Comment: @PinkTux чтобы не повторяться, задайте как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос.

Comment: @PinkTux если ясно [объяснение внизу ответа про isdigit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/385335/23044), то сами можете вместе с вопросом и свой ответ добавить /help/self-answer

Comment: Ага, спасибо, понял. Windows со времён XP в руках не держал :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static int my_sum( char *src, size_t max )
{
    int sum = 0;
    char *endptr;

    while( *src ) {
        char c;
        while( *src && !isdigit( *src ) )
            ++src;

        c = 0;
        if( strlen( src ) > max ) {
            c = src[max];
            src[max] = 0;
        }
        sum += strtol( src, &endptr, 10 );
        if( c )
            src[max] = c;
        src = endptr;
    }

    return sum;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char *s = strdup( argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "dfg1234er45", 2 );
    int sum = my_sum( s );
    printf( "%d\n", sum );
    free( s );
    return sum;
}
```