# Как сравнить цифры в двух строках типа string на C++?

Tags: c++, строки, int

Например даны две строки:

```
Y37W90
```

```
e389r758m3q1179
```

Я хочу итерироваться по обеим строкам и сравнить в них цифры. Хочу сделать это с помощью двух указателей, но не знаю как правильно цифры типа string перевести в тип int для сравнения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как конвертировать символ в цифру?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/50533/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83)

Comment: А зачем переводить? просто идете в обеих строках посимвольно, пока `isdigit` для очередного символа не даст `true` — после чего сравниваете два *символа*. Ведь что, например, сравнение двух `'5'`, что сравнение двух `5 == '5' - '0'` — дадут один и тот же результат. Если это не то, что вам нужно — то сформулируйте свой вопрос более точно.

Comment: `string` это контейнер, содержащий массив данных типа `char`, который совместим с типом `int` (на х86 тип char знаковый, т.о. от типа int он отличается лишь размером (т.е. диапазоном возможных значений)). Десятичные цифры в этом массиве представлены своими кодами (обычно ascii). Поэтому вы можете их сравнивать как числа (т.е. int)

Answer (score 1):

Вам и не надо переводить ничего в int, ведь в c++ ('1' > '4') выдаст false, иначе говоря, вы можете сравнивать цифры прямо в char!

Comment: Тут надо уточнить, что такой метод сработает только для двух цифр и основан на сравнении порядковых номеров символов, но никак не числовых значений. Если нужно будет сравнить числа с двумя и более цифрами, такой метод не сработает.

Comment: В вопросе говорили про цифры, да и я в ответе написал что цифры можно сравнивать. Однако да, числа так сравнивать никак нельзя)